# Kind of multiplicative total boundedness in Hausdorff compact rings

Tags: gn.general-topology, topological-groups, counterexamples

Let $(R,\cal T)$ be a unital Hausdorff compact [topological ring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_ring) and let $A$ be an open subset of $R$ containing $1$. Is there a finite set $B$ with $AB=R$?

Comment: If $A$ is an open proper ideal, there is no such $B$, finite or infinite.

Comment: Yes. I edited the question.

Comment: I might be missing something but doesn´t it follow immediately from compactness?

Comment: @RamirodelaVega: How? Notice that even if $A$ is open, $Ab$ is not necessarily open (e.g., when $b=0$).

Comment: @EmilJeřábek: Of course! I was under the (obviously wrong) impresion that $x \mapsto xb$ was a homeomorphism... as if it was a group operation.

Comment: The question is a duplicate of [my MSE question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/364340/an-example-of-a-compact-multiplicatively-unbounded-ring)

Comment: @AlexRavsky seems so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not in general.

Following your title let us say that a monoid $(M,\cdot,1)$ is totally bounded if for every identity nbd $A$ there exists a finite set $B$ st $AB=M$.
Observe that a (continuous) homomorphic image of a totally bounded monoid is totally bounded.

An example of a compact monoid which is not totally bounded is the monoid $(\{0,1,2,\ldots,\infty\},+,0)$, where $\infty$ is an absorbing point for addition and the topology is seen as the one point compactification of the discrete set $\mathbb{N}$. This is clear by taking $A=\{0\}$.

An example of a compact ring whose multiplicative monoid is not totally bounded
is the ring of $p$-adic integers (for a fixed prime $p$), as the valuation map
$$ (\mathbb{Z}_p,\cdot,1) \to (\{0,1,2,\ldots,\infty\},+,0) $$
is a surjective continuous homomorphism of monoids and the image is not totally bounded.

Comment: This seems correct, but maybe a little on the terse side? To match with the $A$ of the OP, let's denote the valuation as $v: \mathbb{Z}_p \to \mathbb{N} \cup \{\infty\}$ and put $A = v^{-1}(0)$. Then if $B \subset \mathbb{Z}_p$ is finite, we have $v(B A) = v(\bigcup_{b \in B} bA) = \bigcup_{b \in B} v(b) + v(A) = \{v(b): b \in B\}$, which is finite, so $BA$ can't possibly be all of $\mathbb{Z}_p$.

Comment: @Todd it's a counterexample, there is no much to be said after giving it...

Comment: Yet, I considerably expanded it.